# Form fields fail validation on mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik, yup

PROBLEM: Form validation and async requests work well on desktop, fails on mobile devices

TECH USED: nextjs, formik and yup.

VERBOSE:

Made a simple form submission site which works just fine on desktop – validation and all. However, it's a different story on mobile devices – iphone and ipad, not sure about android devices as I don't have any. When filling in a field it works as expected, however, once touching away or going to the next field, it shows a validation error as if the field was left empty. After removing the validation the request (submitting the form) just hangs indefinitely

Not sure what could be at fault here, first time I've come across something like this

[image: Mobile form error]

[image: Desktop form no error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research the most common problem for issues in apple devices are regular expressions. The app works fine after removing them, so might wanna check if you have a similar bug and rework your regexes to work on safari – then they should work on other devices as well.